# Carousel Slider in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, menu, slider

I have carousal slider but when i slide the image it takes me to the next page instead of next image in slider. What can i do to fix the problem.

```
CarouselSlider(
                                  items: widget.catData["tradeWithPictures"]
                                      .map<Widget>((e) {
                                    return Container(
                                      width: Get.width,
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        imageUrl: e['url'],
                                        placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                            Icon(Icons.error),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                  carouselController:
                                      postController.carouselController,
                                  options: CarouselOptions(

                                    autoPlay: true,
                                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,



                                    height: Get.height * .7,
                                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                                    enlargeCenterPage: false,
                                    aspectRatio: 1 / 1.3,
                                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                     // postController.tradeImagesIndex(index);
                                     // postController.carouselController.nextPage();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want page, use pageview instead carousel
https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded